# Is it possible to filter values using a 2D array in SQL?

Tags: sql, arrays, aspen

I have a table with three columns, that can be represented as follows:

```
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
|---|---|---|
| A | B | C |    
| B | C | A |
| C | A | B |
```

And a 2D-Array, like this:

```
[
 [A,B,C],
 [C,A,B],
 [B,A,C]
        ]
```

I would like to select only the rows in the table matching one of the rows in the 2D array.

The obvious solution is to loop through the and make 3 queries, but I am wondering if there is any way to make this in a single `SELECT`

---

Edit: A working example for the 'loop method'.

```
SET LOG_ROWS = 0;
DECLARE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE MODULE.X(col1 char(1), col2 char(1), col3 char(1));

local array, i integer;

REDIM(array,3,3);
array[0,0] = 'A';
array[0,1] = 'B';
array[0,2] = 'C';
array[1,0] = 'C';
array[1,1] = 'A';
array[1,2] = 'B';
array[2,0] = 'B';
array[2,1] = 'A';
array[2,2] = 'C';


INSERT INTO MODULE.X VALUES('A','B','C');
INSERT INTO MODULE.X VALUES('B','C','A');
INSERT INTO MODULE.X VALUES('C','A','B');

FOR i = 0 TO UBound(array) DO
    SELECT * FROM MODULE.X WHERE col1 = array[i,0] AND col2 = array[i,1] AND col3 = array[i,2];
END
```

Result:

```
col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
A    B    C
col1 col2 col3
---- ---- ----
C    A    B
```

Comment: The simple answer is just to use a `JOIN`...  `SELECT * FROM table t INNER JOIN yourData d ON a.col1 = d.col1 AND a.col2 = d.col3 AND a.col3 = d.col3`...   How is your 2d array represented?  As a variable *(look in to using the function `table()` to turn it in to a table)*?  As a table *(just do the join)*?

Comment: `2D-Array` ? Is that mean you have a data in `varray` ?

Comment: Please show us the code of your stored procedure ([edit] your question do **not** post code in comments)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added a working script.

Comment: @XING, yes indeed. If looked at in the debugger, the variable `array` in my example is of type varray.

Comment: @Maxime Which database you are using. The code you posted is certainly not Oracle.

Comment: @XING It's AspenTech's InfoPlus21